# Following Java Tutorial - Code Won't Run

Tags: java

I've been following a java tutorials who has began learning via Sam's teach yourself java and although I have copied this to ensure I can run it before I begin to change and make it my own, it will not run and I am not sure why. I would appreciate if one of you guys/girls could help. I've put my java classes in the correct packages, but it doesn't run. Thanks.

```
Created dir: I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\build
Updating property file: I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\build\classes
Created dir: I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\build\empty
Created dir: I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 3 source files to I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\build\classes
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:14: error: ')' expected
        store.addItem("C01", "MUG, "9.99", "150");
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:14: error: not a statement
        store.addItem("C01", "MUG, "9.99", "150");
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:14: error: ';' expected
        store.addItem("C01", "MUG, "9.99", "150");
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:14: error: unclosed string literal
        store.addItem("C01", "MUG, "9.99", "150");
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: ';' expected
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: ';' expected
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:16: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: ';' expected
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: ';' expected
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: ';' expected
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: not a statement
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201c'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:17: error: illegal character: '\u201d'
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\src\Package1\Giftshop.java:18: error: ';' expected
        store.sort());
27 errors
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:923: The following error occurred while executing this line:
I:\Year 2\Java\NetBeansProjects\Portfolio 1\nbproject\build-impl.xml:263: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

```
package com.jackson.ecommerce;

import java.util.*;

public class Item implements Comparable {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double retail;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    Item(String idIn, String nameIn, String retailIn, String quanIn) {
        id = idIn;
        name = nameIn;
        retail = Double.parseDouble(retailIn);

        if (quantity > 400)
            price = retail * 5D;
        else if (quantity > 200)
            price = retail * .6D;
        else
            price = retail * .7D;
        price = Math.floor( price * 100 + .5) / 100;

    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Item temp = (Item)obj;
        if (this.price < temp.price)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public double GetRetail(){
        return retail;
    }

    public int getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPrice(){
        return price;

    }
}
```

```
package com.jackson.ecommerce;

import java.util.*;

public class Storefront {
    private LinkedList catalog = new LinkedList();

    public void addItem(String id, String name, String price, String quant){

        Item it = new Item(id, name, price, quant);
        catalog.add(it);
    }

    public Item getItem(int i){
        return (Item)catalog.get(i);
    }

    public int getSize(){
        return catalog.size();
    }

    public void sort() {
        Collections.sort(catalog);
    }
```

```
package Package1;

import com.jackson.ecommerce.*;

public class Giftshop {
    public static void main(String[] arguments){
        Storefront store = new Storefront();
        store.addItem("C01", "MUG, "9.99", "150");
        store.addItem("C02", "LG MUG", "12.99", "82");
        store.addItem(“C03”, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
        store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
        store.sort());

        for (int i = 0; i < store.getSize(); i++) {
            Item show = (Item)store.getItem(i);
             System.out.println( show.getId() +
              show.getName() +
              show.getRetail() +
             show.getPrice() +
            show.getQuantity());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You get any error or no? If yes show them

Comment: "Doesn't run" is not an adequate description of a problem.

Comment: Don't know if this is the case, but avoid to copy-paste java code from-to MS Word and the like, they often use quotes/double-quotes equivalent, which are not the right characters for a java compiler .

Answer (score 6):

It is because the code uses `“` which is a **UNICODE** character, and not an **ASCII** one, and **cannot be used to denote String literals**.

See here:

```
store.addItem(“C03“, “MOUSEPAD”, “10.49”, “800”);
store.addItem(“D01”, “T SHIRT”, “16.99”, “90”);
```

Change it to `"`.

Comment: Even in the syntax highlighting in the questions you can see that strings in "" are a different colour to "strings" with the unicode characters.  You should be able to see the same in Netbeans +1

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes, that would be easy to spot in NetBeans.